# Gulp task fails because prior task doesn't create required file

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I have a gulp file that contains various task. The first task creates a sass file, and a later task is meant to use that file.
If I ran both tasks explicitly (`gulp sass`, make sure the sass file is created and then run `gulp template-cache`) they work just fine.

However, when running the gulp task concatenating these tasks, the task fails because the file `template-cache` requires is not yet created, even though the `sass` task already claims to be finished.
These are the two gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    sass(PATH.APP + '/**/*.scss', {sourcemap: true, style: 'expanded', compass: true})
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers:['last 4 versions']}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.APP))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('template-cache', function () {
    return gulp.src(PATH.APP + '/*/**/*.html')
    .pipe(templateCache({ filename:'templates.js', module:'app' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.DIST + '/scripts'));
});
```

This is the gulp task performing the build:

```
gulp.task('default', sequence(
    ['sass', 'replace-config-local'],
    'build',
    'icons',
    'revision'
    ,'uglify'
));
```

And this is the build task:

`gulp.task('build', sequence('clean', ['useref', 'template-cache'], 'concat', 'delete-templates'));`

The error message I get is:

```
gulp
[16:41:37] Using gulpfile ~/backoffice/gulpfile.js
[16:41:37] Starting 'default'...
[16:41:37] Starting 'sass'...
[16:41:37] Finished 'sass' after 46 ms
[16:41:37] Starting 'replace-config-local'...
[16:41:37] Finished 'replace-config-local' after 84 ms
[16:41:37] Starting 'build'...
[16:41:37] Starting 'clean'...
[16:41:37] Finished 'clean' after 14 ms
[16:41:37] Starting 'useref'...
[16:41:38] Starting 'template-cache'...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error: File not found with singular glob: /home/ubuntu/backoffice/app/styles/main.css
  at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/index.js:65:28)
  at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
  at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
  at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at Glob.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:40:16)
  at Glob.g (events.js:260:16)
  at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
  at Glob.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at Glob._finish (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:172:8)
  at done (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:159:12)
  at Glob._processSimple2 (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:652:12)
  at /home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:640:10
  at Glob._stat2 (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:736:12)
  at lstatcb_ (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:728:12)
  at RES (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:23:14)
  at f (/home/ubuntu/backoffice/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Comment: Your `sass` should return the stream, otherwise Gulp won't know it's finished. But aside from that, I don't really understand what's wrong. The `template-cache` task doesn't use anything made by the `sass` task. It only looks for HTML files whereas the `sass` task outputs CSS. They don't seem to be related in any way. Seems like the error is coming from something else.

Comment: Thanks @MadScone, you are right on both accounts. We found the bug today and it was indeed caused by not returning the stream.
The template-cache was not the task failing, it was the useref task, which was running parallel to it. If you'll post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @MadScone, I'm adding your comment as an answer and accepting it, if you want to do it yourself to get the credit feel free and I'll erase my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadScone suggested in his comment, returning the stream solved the problem.
For example, changing `gulp.src(PATH.DIST + '/**')` to `return gulp.src(PATH.DIST + '/**')`.